# Chat.meta, no way to return to Meta proper

Tags: feature-request, chat

If I missed this, please let me know, else I would like to request a link back to meta.stackoverflow.com from the chat rooms.  I think having the standard footer located here now would suffice, perhaps slightly modded since it is a different site.  However, just like I can go to SU, Meta, SO, ServerFault from the footer in any of those sites, I think you should be able to leave the chat section without having to retype in a URL.

**Edit**

I was here when I made this observation (chat room home page I guess?).  I had hit the 'HOME" link from a chat room, then began to look for the link back to meta at that point.  The link pointed out in the answer below isn't there, but good to know it does exists somewhere.

[image]

Comment: Now that there's a logo in the chat header linking to the Meta, there's a proper way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

**Edit re your edit:** Okay, so you where not *in* a room. Yeah, that page could indeed need a link back to the mother ship.

Comment: We should perhaps add the SE logo etc, a bit more like the current SE headers.

Comment: I updated the request showing where I was when I 'got stuck'

Answer (score 1):

There is a link, but it's called `q&a` and it's in the lower left corner of the page.  You just happened to cut it out of your image.  I suggested during the private beta that it should retain the meta.stackoverflow.com text, but apparently I was ignored.

[image: back link text]

Comment: Yeah I didn't even try that link as it doesn't sound anything like a return to meta link.